# OMDb API: search for title of movie returns null

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to connect my api so that when i search for the title of a movie, it returns that information from OMDb, but it keeps returning null and i can't figure out why.

Here's my interface:

```
@FeignClient(url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/", name ="Challenge-inc")
public interface Interface_api_omdb {

    @GetMapping("?t={titulo}&apikey=mykey")
    Filme buscaFilmePorTitulo(@PathVariable("titulo") String titulo);
}
```

and here's my controller:

```
    @Autowired
    private Interface_api_omdb interface_api_omdb;
    
    @GetMapping("/{titulo}")
    public ResponseEntity<Filme> getTitulo(@PathVariable String titulo)
    {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(interface_api_omdb.buscaFilmePorTitulo(titulo)); 
    }
```

I would really appreciate the help, because i need to do the rest of the API but without this i can't proceed. Thanks.